# ROTH IRA eligibility for US Citizens working abroad and claiming FEIE (foreign earned income exclusion)

Tags: roth-ira

I've been working overseas for the past few years for a US company and claiming FEIE. My annual salary is roughly 200k, which is over the income eligibility requirements for a ROTH IRA. As a work around for the salary requirements, I was told that it's possible to open a backdoor IRA, which is essentially opening up a Traditional IRA and immediately converting it to a ROTH IRA? Will claiming the FEIE cause any implications with opening up a backdoor ROTH IRA?